# How many different abelian groups exist, which include subgroup $ \mathbb Z/12 \mathbb Z$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

How many different abelian groups exist which include subgroup $\mathbb Z/12 \mathbb Z$ and factor by this subgroup is also isomorphic to $\mathbb Z/12 \mathbb Z$?

My suggestion is that we should have group of 144 elements (because of 12 elements in subgroup and 12 classes).
So, group of $144 $ elements can be decomposed into these 4 different direct sums:

$\mathbb Z/144 \mathbb Z$

$\mathbb Z_{12} \times \mathbb Z_{12}$

$\mathbb Z_{3} \times \mathbb Z_{4} \times \mathbb Z_{12}$

$\mathbb Z_{3} \times \mathbb Z_{4} \times \mathbb Z_{3} \times \mathbb Z_{4}$

which includes subgroups isomorphic to  $\mathbb Z/12 \mathbb Z$

And it means that the answer is "4".

Am I right?

Comment: Perhaps you meant "abelian groups"=commutative groups?

Comment: $\mathbb Z_{12}$ and $\mathbb Z_3\times\mathbb Z_4$ are isomorphic, so your answer is not correct.

Comment: Perhaps too obviously, just giving groups of order $144$ is not sufficient. You should verify that they have a subgroup isomorphic to $\Bbb{Z}/12\Bbb{Z}$ with corresponding quotient also isomorphic to $\Bbb{Z}/12\Bbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 4):

A consequence of the Chinese Remainder theorem is that, if $n = ab$, then
$$\mathbb{Z}_{n} \cong \mathbb{Z}_a \times \mathbb{Z}_b \iff \gcd(a,b) = 1.$$

The prime decomposition of $144 = 2^4 \cdot 3^2$, so we can list all Abelian groups of order $144$ (up to isomorphism) as follows:

1. $\mathbb{Z}_{2} \times \mathbb{Z}_{2} \times \mathbb{Z}_{2} \times \mathbb{Z}_{2} \times \mathbb{Z}_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_3$
2. $\mathbb{Z}_{2} \times \mathbb{Z}_{2} \times \mathbb{Z}_{2} \times \mathbb{Z}_{2} \times \mathbb{Z}_9$
3. $\mathbb{Z}_{2} \times \mathbb{Z}_{2} \times \mathbb{Z}_{4} \times \mathbb{Z}_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_3$
4. $\mathbb{Z}_{2} \times \mathbb{Z}_{2} \times \mathbb{Z}_{4} \times \mathbb{Z}_9$
5. $\mathbb{Z}_{2} \times \mathbb{Z}_{8} \times \mathbb{Z}_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_3$
6. $\mathbb{Z}_{2} \times \mathbb{Z}_{8} \times \mathbb{Z}_9$
7. $\mathbb{Z}_{4} \times \mathbb{Z}_{4} \times \mathbb{Z}_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_3$
8. $\mathbb{Z}_{4} \times \mathbb{Z}_{4} \times \mathbb{Z}_9$
9. $\mathbb{Z}_{16} \times \mathbb{Z}_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_3$
10. $\mathbb{Z}_{16} \times \mathbb{Z}_9$

We now have to determine which of these have a subgroup isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{12} \cong \mathbb{Z}_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_4$. This is the case if and only if you have a component $\mathbb{Z}_n$ with $4|n$ and a componenet $\mathbb{Z}_m$ with $3|m$, hence:

1. Nope.
2. Nope.
3. Yes, take the subgroup generated by $(0,0,1,1,0)$
4. Yes, take the subgroup generated by $(0,0,1,3)$.
5. Yes, take the subgroup generated by $(0,2,1,0)$.
6. Yes, take the subgroup generated by $(0,2,3)$.
7. Yes, take the subgroup generated by $(1,0,1,0)$.
8. Yes, take the subgroup generated by $(1,0,3)$.
9. Yes, take the subgroup generated by $(4,1,0)$.
10. Yes, take the subgroup generated by $(4,3)$.

Finally, the quotient must also be isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{12} \cong \mathbb{Z}_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_4$. Note that $\mathbb{Z}_8 / \mathbb{Z}_4 \cong \mathbb{Z}_2$; $\mathbb{Z}_{16} / \mathbb{Z}_4 \cong \mathbb{Z}_4$ and $\mathbb{Z}_9 / \mathbb{Z}_3 \cong \mathbb{Z}_3$, hence:

3. Quotient is $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2 \times (\mathbb{Z}_4/\mathbb{Z}_4) \times (\mathbb{Z}_3/\mathbb{Z}_3) \times \mathbb{Z}_3 \cong \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_3$
4. Quotient is $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2 \times (\mathbb{Z}_4/\mathbb{Z}_4) \times (\mathbb{Z}_9/\mathbb{Z}_3) \cong \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_3$
5. Quotient is $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times (\mathbb{Z}_8/\mathbb{Z}_4)  \times (\mathbb{Z}_3/\mathbb{Z}_3) \times \mathbb{Z}_3\cong \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_3$
6. Quotient is $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times (\mathbb{Z}_8/\mathbb{Z}_4)  \times (\mathbb{Z}_9/\mathbb{Z}_3) \cong\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_3$
7. Quotient is $(\mathbb{Z}_4/\mathbb{Z}_4) \times \mathbb{Z}_4 \times (\mathbb{Z}_3/\mathbb{Z}_3) \times \mathbb{Z}_3\cong \mathbb{Z}_4 \times \mathbb{Z}_3$
8. Quotient is $(\mathbb{Z}_4/\mathbb{Z}_4) \times \mathbb{Z}_4 \times (\mathbb{Z}_9/\mathbb{Z}_3) \cong\mathbb{Z}_4 \times \mathbb{Z}_3$
9. Quotient is $(\mathbb{Z}_{16}/\mathbb{Z}_4)\times (\mathbb{Z}_3/\mathbb{Z}_3)  \times \mathbb{Z}_3 \cong\mathbb{Z}_4 \times \mathbb{Z}_3$
10. Quotient is $(\mathbb{Z}_{16}/\mathbb{Z}_4)\times (\mathbb{Z}_9/\mathbb{Z}_3)  \cong\mathbb{Z}_4 \times \mathbb{Z}_3$

So, yes, the answer is indeed $4$ - but the way to get there is quite different from what you suggested!

Comment: Thank you very much! Now everything is clear for me with all these quotients and direct sums.

Comment: @IgorKozyrev Well, there you have: the complete and detailed answer that you were *already* beginning to **deduce by yourself** in the last hour or so, step by step...But I guess it is great to receive the whole thing already done completely for you *after you were already beginning to understand stuff*, uh? Fine...

Comment: @DonAntonio, yes, actually I tried to solve this from yesterday. Even dreamed about it :)

Comment: @IgorKozyrev Well, you can stop dreaming about it now: ti's been solved for you...

Answer (score 3):

Observe that $\;\Bbb Z_3\times\Bbb Z_4\cong\Bbb Z_{12}\;$ , so your second, third and fourth groups are the same (up to isomorphism).

Can you see how to fix your answer now?

Comment: So, it's only 2 groups? $\mathbb Z_{12} \times \mathbb Z_{12}$ and $\mathbb Z_{144} $?

Comment: @IgorKozyrev There are more than two factorisations of $144$ into two factors.

Comment: But the other will not include $ \mathbb Z/12 \mathbb Z$ as subgroup. For example, we have  $ \mathbb Z/9 \mathbb Z \otimes \mathbb Z/16 \mathbb Z $ but it will not include $ \mathbb Z/12 \mathbb Z$

Comment: Take the group generated by $(3,4) \in \mathbb{Z}_9 \times \mathbb{Z}_{16}$.

Comment: Ok. Let's consider all the different decompositions which includes the subgroup: $ \mathbb Z/12 \mathbb Z \otimes \mathbb Z/12 \mathbb Z $, $ \mathbb Z/9 \mathbb Z \otimes \mathbb Z/16 \mathbb Z $, $ \mathbb Z/3 \mathbb Z \otimes \mathbb Z/48 \mathbb Z $, $ \mathbb Z/8 \mathbb Z \otimes \mathbb Z/18 \mathbb Z $, $ \mathbb Z/4 \mathbb Z \otimes \mathbb Z/36 \mathbb Z $

Comment: @IgorKozyrev You'll have a subgroup cyclic of order $\;12\;$ iff your subgroup has an element of order $\;3\;$ and an element of order $\;4\;$ ...

Comment: In this case we have these 5 different decompositions with a subgroup cyclic of order 12, that I mentioned in the prevoius comment?

Comment: Well, also $\Bbb Z_2\times\Bbb Z_{72}\;$ has a cyclic subgroup of order $\;12\;$, obviously...And don't use $\;\otimes\;$ , which means way another thing (tensor product) than direct product (or direct sum, as you wish. It's the same in this case) .